# Should I be using a regression model?

Tags: probability

I've been given a question to figure out whether a company will issue a dividend based on percent profit. The mean percent profit for companies which give out dividends is 12, the mean for those who don't is 1.5. They each have a variance of 36, and the percentage of companies which give out dividends is 75. I need to find the likelihood of a company with percent profit of 4 would issue a dividend. This seems like a simple question, but it's been quite a while since my last stats course, and I'm very rusty.